# How to display empty td values which is coming from loop in a table in Rails views

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M5eg.png

I have to show the images in a table td column. So, I wrote the loop for one td to show at least four images according to uploads. But when images attachments less than 4 another column values shifting to this td column. So, I need to display the empty one also. How to solve it. Here is my code

```
<% hp.fi_attachments.last(4).each_with_index do |fi,index| %>  
  <td>  
    <div class="image_address">
      <%= image_tag fi.image, :class => "style_image"%>  
    </div>  
  </td>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% last_four = hp.fi_attachments.last(4) %>
<% 4.times do |index| %>
  <td>
    <% if last_four[index] %>
      <div class="image_address">
        <%= image_tag last_four[index].image, :class => "style_image"%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```